# problema ao preencher formulário com letras maiúsculas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, formulário

pessoal em meu [site](http://oticasreiban.com.br/index.php?route=account/register) o usuário quando vai se cadastrar em meu site os campo onde ele digita texto ele consegue digitar com letras maiúsculas e isso gera um `BUG` em meu site lá no painel gostaria de saber se existe algum validador que não permita que o usuário digite letras maiúsculas pois ele tem que preencher todo o formulário somente com letras minúsculas.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de adicionar no seu banco de dados, converte a string para lowercase. Coloquei o exemplo abaido de como converte em PHP e Java Script para lowercase (letras minusculas).

Em PHP:

```
$string = "TESTE";
echo strtolower($string); //teste
```

Em Javascript:

```
var string = "TESTE";
console.log(string.toLowerCase()); // teste
```

Para forçar o campo ser sempre letras minusculas, ficaria desta forma:

```js
// Função javascript
function lowerCase(input) {
  input.value = input.value.toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
Tente digitar letras maiúsculas:
<input type="text" id="txt" onkeyup="return lowerCase(this)" />​
```

Melhorei o exemplo acima. Você precisa colocar essa função javascript em um arquivo .js e no seu input, colocar `onkeyup="return lowerCase(this)"`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta em javascript como eu insiro isso dentro de um input text por exemplo

Comment: Eu vi sua resposta amigo mais seguinte dessa forma que você fez não exibe na hora para o usuário ?  eu queria uma forma que já exibi-se para ele tudo minusculo no formulário não converter na hora de salvar ele teria que ver as letras serem escritas em minúsculas mesmo com o capslock ligado

Comment: Editei minha resposta, Kirito, olhe se funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o strtolower e converter, antes de enviar pro banco de dados.
[strtolower](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtolower.php)

EDITADO

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// INICIO
function minuscula(a){
v = a.value.toLowerCase();
a.value = v;
}
//FIM
</script>
Como usar
<label>Nome:
<input name="nome" type="text" id="nome" size="50" onkeyup="minuscula(this)" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o ideal seria corrigir de fato o "isso gera um BUG em meu site lá no painel" e passar a suportar os caracteres maiúsculos normalmente.

Entretanto existe o `mb_strtolower()` que permite, razoavelmente, que passe para minusculo os caracteres, *mas ele é bem lento*.

---

Nesse caso coisas como:

```
Inkeliz
ÍnkÊlÍz
ĮŇЌẸĹĮŻ
```

Terá como resultado:

```
inkeliz
ínkêlíz
įňќẹĺįż
```

Mas, isso não é perfeito, porque nem tudo possui caracteres minúsculos (?) ou a função simplesmente ignora, como nos casos:

```
ᾨ
Ⅻ
```